# PHP img src (Need to link variable in another folder)

Tags: php

I'm currently creating a login system. When the user is logged in he/she should be able to upload pictures via a form to my database.
Currently the upload to the database works, which is great!.

But the img source in the database gets uploaded to this url `uploads/cheekycat.png`.
This folder is located in `app/controllers/uploads`.

Now since I'm using `MVC` i have the LOGIC of the program in my models folder, which is located here. `app/models`

In this folder I have this file and in the bottom of it I tried the following

`echo "<img src=<?php echo $pic["imageFullNamePicture"]  ?>>";`

Which is the variable that is linked to the upload directory. But since this model is in another folder it cannot find the folder and echo the pictures!

showPicModel.php

```
<?php
    require_once ("../../Core/database.php");
    class showPicModel extends Database {
        public function showPic() {
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
            echo '<section class="picture-links">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                    <h2>Pictures</h2> ';
            ?>
            <div id="pictures">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE userid = '{$_SESSION['u_id']}'";

                //$sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 20;";
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $pictures = $stmt->fetchAll();

                // if ($pictures !== null) {
                foreach ($pictures as $pic) {
            ?>
                <li>
                    <figure id="<?php echo $pic['id']; ?>">
                          <b>
                            <figcaption><?php echo $pic["titlePicture"] ?>
                            <!-- Fejl er her -->
                            <img src=<?php echo $pic["imageFullNamePicture"]  ?>>
                            <?php echo $pic["descPicture"] ?> <br>
                    </figure>
              </li>
              <?php
            }
          }
        } 
    }
```

This is my controller!
ShowPicController.php

```
<?php


include_once("../../Models/showPicModel.php");

//Use model
$model = new showPicModel();

 if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){
    $model->showPic();
}
```

And this a part of my view which returns the filetitle, filedescription and the image path. The file title and filedesc gets returned from the database, buut not the image since something is wrong with the path!
uploadView.php (Located in app/views/home)

```
<?php
    //Check if user is logged in
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
        include ("../../controllers/ShowPicController.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: If the folder `uploads` is publicly visible and in the root of your folder you could just go with `echo '<img src="//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$pic["imageFullNamePicture"].'" />';`

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you for your answer.

The folder uploads folder is located in htdocs/test/mvc/app/controllers/uploads.

I tried to move the folder around, etc to the root and other locations, while using your suggestion, but with no luck. The website returns the defualt img logo, but not the picture.

the upload folder has to stay in in that controller folder

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!

```
<?php  echo "<img src='../../controllers/" . $pic["imageFullNamePicture"] . "' height='130' width='220'> ";  ?>
```